# How many different numbers can be made using only 5 different numbers out of a set with 7 numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

We have a set $M = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}$
How many different numbers can be made using only 5 different numbers from M?

I assume that is something like $P(5,7)$ or $P(7,5)$ I cannot decide.
On a private class the person solving exercises said $5^7$, but I see that the formula he used is for R-permutations with repetition, but in the exercise is written $5$ DIFFERENT numbers from M.

Can someone explain ?

Comment: I think you mean "how many different SETS OF numbers can be made" or "how many different SEQUENCES OF numbers can be made".

Comment: Think of first choosing the numbers and then permuting them, it should put you out of the dilemma.

Comment: One of  P(5,7) or P(7,5) is zero while the other is the one you want.  Do you understand which?

Comment: For what it's worth, I found it helpful to consider the construction of the number in two stages: first, you select 5 numbers out of 7: this can be done in $\binom{7}{5}$ ways.  Then, once the numbers are selected, they can be permuted in $(5!)$ ways.  This gives you a final computation of $\binom{7}{5} \times 5!.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If repetition is allowed then answer is $7^5$ ,because there are $7$ choice for first digit , $7$ choices for second digits so on such that $7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 = 7^5 $

If repetition is not allowed , then there is $7$ choices for first digit , $6$ for second, $5$ choices for third so on such that $7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 = P(7,5)=2520$

$\color{red}{NOTE}$= Because of it is said that different numbers , the repetition is not allowed ,so answer is $P(7,5)$

Moreover , you can do it such that first select $5$ number from the set by $C(7,5)$ .After that , find the number of how many ways there are to arrange them by $5!$. Then , multiply them such that $C(7,5) \times 5! = P (7,5) =2520$

$\color{red}{NOTE-2:}$ When you work over permutation if $P(m,n)$ ,then $m \geq n$ . If not, then the answer is $0$

Comment: yes thank you, this helps very much, the note 2 is not exactly declared in our lectures and I had some trouble deciding what is what, this subject is a little hard for me

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation, this is my first time using this site
Thank you, I will ask some more since I have the exam on Tuesday...